# mongo can not connect to remote machine?

Tags: mongodb, shell, authentication

I connect to my remote mongo machine with mongo shell:

```
mongo 192.168.1.83/dbname -u username -p password
```

I use this command in my **remote machine**, it is **ok**, but when I run this command in **my machine**, it returns **error**:

```
Wed Sep 23 10:30:17.529 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB by default, it will allow connections only from the local interface(The box which you installed your mongo)

To Enable remote connections

- In mongodb.conf file add the ip address of the machine from which you are trying to connect the mongo running on a remote machine in the bind_ip.

Reference:

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/